# Ruby add lines to block (Proc) of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Example is simple and I need solution for Ruby **1.8.7**

**EDIT**
Added `Ramaze` call to better explain need for edit of block. I want a way to change block so that I can wrap in `rescue` block and log if thread fails. API [link](http://ramaze.net/documentation/Innate/SingletonMethods.html#defer-instance_method)

```
class Foo
  def self.execute(&block)
    # Remaze will create new thread to execute the block
    # I want to change block so that I can add rescue in case thread fails
    Ramaze::defer(block)
  end
end
```

Usage

```
Foo.execute do
  puts "Hello!!!"
end
# => Hello!!!
```

What I am trying to do, is add few lines of code to `&block` so e.g. `puts "World!!!` at the end but dynamically. Real world implementation is I have a class that defers creation of threads, I want to add `rescue` block before I defer thread's creation. That way I do not need to scratch my head whenever threads fail.

Thank you.

Comment: I know there is a gem that does this as well, that would be helpful too. Cannot seem to find it now.

Comment: You could wrap that proc in another proc and call that.

Comment: Why don't you just call puts after the call? e.g. `def self.execute(&block) block.call; puts "ho"; end` Or wrap the block into another…

Comment: Can you modify Foo.execute? Or would you need to override it?

Comment: Edited question so it better explains my need for edit of the block. Hehe wanted to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out solution is very simple, just did not have experience with blocks to see it right away. Something that Sergio suggested.

```
class Foo
  def self.execute(&block)
    Ramaze::defer(&wrap(&block))
  end

  private

  def self.wrap(&block)
    return lambda do
     begin
      yield
      rescue Exception => e
       Log.error "[ERROR IN THREAD] #{e.message}, #{e.backtrace}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```